# Webdriver fails to click element after a WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

First, I was facing an issue that selenium webdriver was not always finding the element and clicking, and I found that WebDriverWait should solve the problem. So, I used this code, for instance:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside/div/nav/ul/li[3]/a"))).click();
```

But now I am having a timeout issue, Observing the test to run, I can see that the element is being hover(because it changes the color), but webdriver is not clicking.

Does anyone have tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Any XPath that starts with "html" is guaranteed to be unreliable. If you provide a [mcve], maybe we can help you. As it is, this is probably going to to get closed as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: please provide HTML code to check xpath of element.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend refactoring like this, to separate the wait from the click event.  Otherwise, its hard to diagnose the cause of your click failure:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By locator = By.xpath(".//ul/li[3]/a");
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator))
   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
try {
   we.click();
} catch (WebDriverException wde)
{
   LOGGER.info("Click failed.", wde);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the wait and then try JavascriptExecutor to click on your element

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(YOUR Locator);

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)